# Stay hidden after fadeout

Tags: jquery, css

I have a logo in a preloader div that I want to fade out Up after a call.
The logo does fadeoutup but becomes visible after it's faded out completely.
What I want is to keep it faded out or make it display none with CSS only if possible I can use jquery but rather not.

```
&.preloader-remove{
            -webkit-animation: fadeOutUp 1s;
            animation: fadeOutUp 1s;
        }
```

Css Animation

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeOutUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeOutUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  }
}

.fadeOutUp {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeOutUp;
  animation-name: fadeOutUp;
}
```

Comment: What does the animation css look like?

Comment: It just fades out while moving up.

Comment: I meant the css for the animation. You should still add it to your question even if you got an answer so that others can see if they're making the same mistake.

Comment: Ah ofcourse just added to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a css transition rather than animation:

```
&.preloader-remove {
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: top 1s, opacity 1s;
    transition: top 1s, opacity 1s;
}
```

Comment: Stupid me I just had to add the opacity to 0... Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

From the jquery api:http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

.fadeOut()
Description: Hide the matched elements by fading them to transparent.

```
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#book" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

Comment: By using this the element doesn't move up. I got it fixed by using the solution below. Thanks anyway!